# Is a filtered RDD still in cache when performed on a cached RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm wondering if we perform the following instructions :

```
val rdd : = sc.textFile("myfile").zipwithIndex.cache
val size = rdd.count
val filter = rdd.filter(_._2 % 2 == 0)
val sizeF = filter.count
```

The action performed on the filter RDD is execute as if it is in cache or not ? Despite the fact we create a second RDD from the first one, the information came from the same place, so i'm wondering if it is copied into a new object that needs to be cached or if the filtered object is directly linked to his parent allowing faster actions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `filter` is a *transformation* and not an *action*, and since spark is *lazy* nothing was actually done in the following line:

```
val filter = rdd.filter(_._2 % 2 == 0)
```

The following line:

```
val sizeF = filter.count
```

Will use the cached() `rdd`, and will perform the `filter` transformation followed by the `count` action

Hence, there is nothing to `cache` in the `filter` transformation.

[Spark Guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html)

> **Transformations**
>
> The following table lists some of the common transformations supported
>   by Spark. Refer to the RDD API doc (Scala, Java, Python, R) and pair
>   RDD functions doc (Scala, Java) for details.
>
> filter(func)  Return a new dataset formed by selecting those elements
>   of the source on which func returns true.

Note. if `filter` was an action, and a new RDD was created, it wouldn't be `cached`, only the RDDs which the `cache()` operation was executed on them are `cached`.

Answer (score 0):

No,

The child RDD will not be cahced, the cache will mantain the original RDD in your workers and the other data will not be cached.

If you request for this filtered RDD other step that doesn't change the data, the response always will be fast due to Spark keep the Spark Files in workers until a real change.